# Echoing out session array in loop does not work

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am having a weird problem echoing out a session array. I would like to accomplish the following:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($_SESSION['medication']);$i++){
    echo $_SESSION['medication'][$i];
}
```

In fact it echoes out all fields of the array and then *afterwards* displays the well known error message "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string".

However, when I just echo out field 0 all the time in the loop instead of field $i, it works fine without error message.

Why is there an error message triggered?

UPDATE 1

`var_dump($_SESSION['medication'])` echoes out a bunch of stuff:

```
array(12) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> int(10) [2]=> string(2) "14" [3]=> string(2) "17" [4]=> object(stdClass)#1 (7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "AUGMENTIN" ["strength"]=> string(6) "875 mg" ["sig"]=> string(29) "1 tablet by mouth twice a day" ["quantity"]=> string(6) "twenty" ["refills"]=> string(4) "zero" ["treatmentfor"]=> string(17) "sinus, bronchitis" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#2 (7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["name"]=> string(8) "DIFLUCAN" ["strength"]=> string(6) "150 mg" ["sig"]=> string(47) "1 tablet by mouth as needed for yeast infection" ["quantity"]=> string(3) "one" ["refills"]=> string(3) "one" ["treatmentfor"]=> string(27) "yeast, other abx for female" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#3 (7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["name"]=> string(14) "MEDROL DOSEPAK" ["strength"]=> string(1) "-" ["sig"]=> string(135) "6 PO Qday x 1 day, then 5 PO Qday x 1 day, then 4 PO Qday x 1 day, then 3 PO Qday x1 day, then 2 PO Qday x 1 day then 1 PO Qday x 1 day" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "21" ["refills"]=> string(4) "zero" ["treatmentfor"]=> string(17) "allergic rhinitis" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#4 (7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "17" ["name"]=> string(23) "FLUTICASONE NASAL SPRAY" ["strength"]=> string(6) "0.0005" ["sig"]=> string(91) "1 spray each nostril twice a day, reducing to 1 spray per nostril per day when appropriate." ["quantity"]=> string(10) "one bottle" ["refills"]=> string(3) "one" ["treatmentfor"]=> string(17) "allergic rhinitis" } [8]=> object(stdClass)#5 (7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "AUGMENTIN" ["strength"]=> string(6) "875 mg" ["sig"]=> string(29) "1 tablet by mouth twice a day" ["quantity"]=> string(6) "twenty" ["refills"]=> string(4) "zero" ["treatmentfor"]=> string(17) "sinus, bronchitis" } [9]=> object(stdClass)#6 (7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["name"]=> string(8) "DIFLUCAN" ["strength"]=> string(6) "150 mg" ["sig"]=> string(47) "1 tablet by mouth as needed for yeast infection" ["quantity"]=> string(3) "one" ["refills"]=> string(3) "one" ["treatmentfor"]=> string(27) "yeast, other abx for female" } [10]=> object(stdClass)#7 (7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["name"]=> string(14) "MEDROL DOSEPAK" ["strength"]=> string(1) "-" ["sig"]=> string(135) "6 PO Qday x 1 day, then 5 PO Qday x 1 day, then 4 PO Qday x 1 day, then 3 PO Qday x1 day, then 2 PO Qday x 1 day then 1 PO Qday x 1 day" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "21" ["refills"]=> string(4) "zero" ["treatmentfor"]=> string(17) "allergic rhinitis" } [11]=> object(stdClass)#8 (7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "17" ["name"]=> string(23) "FLUTICASONE NASAL SPRAY" ["strength"]=> string(6) "0.0005" ["sig"]=> string(91) "1 spray each nostril twice a day, reducing to 1 spray per nostril per day when appropriate." ["quantity"]=> string(10) "one bottle" ["refills"]=> string(3) "one" ["treatmentfor"]=> string(17) "allergic rhinitis" } }
```

UPDATE 2

I have found the problem: later in the code I use the variable $medication which seems to refer to the session. How come? Is register_globals on?

UPDATE 3 - SOLUTION FOUND
register_globals was indeed on (how embarrassing) and I turned it off. It related to the other variable $medication. Now it works fine. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: show us the `var_dump($_SESSION['medication'])` please. Thanks.

Comment: try a `var_dump($_SESSION['medication']);`

Comment: what are you storing in 'medication'? Is it an array? Show more hint.

Comment: @tunmisefasipe I am storing different medications in the session array. Please see question edit for var_dump()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have something other than a string stored in that index of the session array.  In this case, it seems you have a `stdClass` object in the array.

Also, since you can have non-numeric array indices, using a foreach loop will yield better results.

```
foreach($_SESSION['medication'] as $index => $value) {
    if (is_scalar($value)) {
        echo "$index = $value<br />";
    } else {
        echo "<pre>$index = " . print_r($value, true) . "</pre><br />";
    }
}
```

[is_scalar](http://php.net/is_scalar) will check to see if the variable can be echo'ed (string, int, float, bool), otherwise we will [print_r](http://php.net/print_r) the value.

Comment: This was very helpful and showed me what was in the array so thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to loop over an array with a `for`? `foreach` was designed specifically to iterate over arrays.

Try:

```
foreach($_SESSION['medication'] as $foo){
    echo $foo;
}
```

You're likely storing an object in `$_SESSION['medication']` as others have suggested. You should try `var_dump($_SESSION['medication']);` to see what's actually stored in there, if there is actually an object (`stdClass`) in there, you'll want to remove it before running your loop as you can't echo a class.

Edit:

`$_SESSION['medication'][4]` and all elements after that contain an object as the value, you'll have to do something other than echo it (try print_r like others have suggested)

Comment: I normally use foreach, too, but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Theres an object of type StdClass in that session array that cant be echo'd

Also, use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)